# People Result Sorting Issue in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, people-search

We are trying to sort people result so the when users search for a user name, for example John, we should see the result sorted by last name in ascending order:
John A
John B
John C ....etc

So in a development box (single SP 2013 server) we did the following:
1. Edited **LastName** managed property (in search schema) and activated the box **Sortable** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

We crawled the content database, and then we created a result source based on **Local People Results** and under **sorting** tab we selected **LastName** managed property and the sort order ascending as shown below:

[image]

these steps worked perfectly in the development environment, but it did not work in the production one, and the only difference is that the current production has content sources that would take weeks to do a full crawl (those content sources to crawl other SharePoint farms) and the only full crawl I did on production was for local content and that is including mysites (http and sps3 protocols) and I think that should be it since the crawled propeties mapped to **LastName** are **People:LastName, People:SPS-PhoneticLastName** I could be wrong though...I have tried a full user profile import and did full crawl for local contents to no avail...I am lost and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: You can split out the SPS3 crawl as a separate content source so that it crawls faster. You are correct, after a Full crawl you should be able to replicate the results from the development environment.

Comment: Thanks Mathew...we have a separate content source for MySites and SPS3 and it takes 15 minutes to do full crawl..I have crawled the content several time to no avail.. I am not sure how to trouble shoot the issue, or if I can if I can add the sort logic manually to the query string.

Comment: Are you updating the Schema in the Search Service Application? (Updating the Schema for People at the Site Collection will have no effect, you have to change the schema at the SSA.)

Comment: Hello Mathew...I am doing the change in CA in Search Application. I am not sure if the issue is due to custom solution we have in our farm since I see the same behavior in the UAT farm too, but not in the OOTB SharePoint Development server.

Comment: I would troubleshoot the custom solution.